# Creating top 10 movie recommendations for all users in a dataset using neural networks using Pytorch

Tags: python, split, pytorch, neural-network

I am new to both Pytorch and neural networks and have a question about what to do after finishing training and testing the movie recommender system.

So far I have a neural network recommender system with Pytorch that runs in 10 epochs. In each epoch, the model trains in batches using a for loop and the trainloader, then the model is put in evaluation mode and I test the model in batches using a for loop on the testloader.

Now I would like to get the top 10 recommendations for all the users in my dataset(both test and train users and recommendations), but I am a bit confused. After my understanding, I can't then split the dataset into batches as I want to run the model on the entire dataset at the same time. Am I wrong and do I need to split the full datasets into batches now as well? If so how do I split it so that one user has all its ratings in one batch(if that is necessary?)

Any input, help, or explanation on how this would be done is very much appreciated! Also, let me know if any additional information is needed from me. Thank you